# Como fazer a scrollbar de uma div ficar sobreposta ao conteúdo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso fazer uma tabela, que terá conteúdo dinâmico (suas "tr" serão adicionadas ou removidas pelo usuário).

Se a tabela chegar em determinado tamanho, uma scrollbar deverá aparecer no "tbody" para que o usuário posso "rolar" entre as "tr's" dele.
O "thead" deverá aparecer em todo momento, e a scrollbar não poderá sobrepô-lo, ela apenas deverá sobrepor o "tbody".

Esse seria um esboço de como deve ser:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaGnT.png

Eu consegui chegar exatamente no resultado que eu quero usando:

```
table tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: overlay;
}
```

**Gif com o resultado no Chrome:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlTFb.gif

Mas apenas tive esse resultado no Chrome e Edge, quando fui testar no Firefox a scrollbar simplesmente não aparece.

**Gif com o resultado no Firefox:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D24pO.gif

Aparentemente isso ocorre pois o Firefox não é compatível com a propriedade `Overflow: overlay`, que está aplicada no `tbody`.
Durante minhas pesquisas, encontrei uma documentação da MDN(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) dizendo que `overlay` foi descontinuada, ou seja, não seria recomendável utiliza-la.

**Sendo assim, existiria alguma forma de resolver esse problema no firefox, ou então outra maneira fazer uma scrollbar sobreposta apenas com HTML, CSS ou até mesmo JS???**

OBS1: a melhor maneira que eu consegui de contornar o problema foi colocando dois "overflow's" no `tbody`, mas isso faz com que tenha duas scrollbars diferentes, uma para cada navegador.

**Gif com o resultado no Firefox:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiQQ0.gif

```
table tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;   /* Para aparecer apenas no Firefox*/
  overflow: overlay;  /* Para substituir a scrollbar de cima se o navegador for chrome ou edge */

  scrollbar-width: thin; /* Para aparecer apenas no Firefox*/
  scrollbar-color: blue transparent; /* Para aparecer apenas no Firefox*/
}
```

O problema nesse caso é que a scrollbar do firefox não sobrepõem o conteúdo do "tbody" (como no chrome), e se eu coloco sua cor como "transparent", ela pega a cor do elemento pai e não do conteúdo.

OBS2: a mesma pergunta foi feita em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253887/how-to-make-scrollbar-overlapping-page-content mas não chegaram em uma conclusão.

OBS3: Ainda não comecei a fazer o JS pois travei nesse problema.

(Edit)Codepen:
https://codepen.io/devgustavosantos/pen/abYNvaJ

Código atual:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Teste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Idade</th>
          <th>Profissão</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Ted</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Estudante</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ralf</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>Designer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ted</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Estudante</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ralf</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>Designer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ted</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Estudante</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ralf</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>Designer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ted</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Estudante</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ralf</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>Designer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ted</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Estudante</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ralf</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>Designer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ted</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Estudante</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ralf</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>Designer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ted</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Estudante</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ralf</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>Designer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ted</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Estudante</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ralf</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>Designer</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}

table thead {
  background: green;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
}

table thead tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

table thead tr th {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

table tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;   /* Para aparecer apenas no Firefox*/
  overflow: overlay;  /* Para substituir a scrollbar de cima se o navegador for chrome ou edge */

  scrollbar-width: thin; /* Para aparecer apenas no Firefox*/
  scrollbar-color: blue transparent; /* Para aparecer apenas no Firefox*/
}

table tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 22px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
}

table tbody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 8rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 6px blue;
  border: solid 8px transparent;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgb(255, 217, 0);
}

table tbody tr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

table tbody tr td:last-child {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Por acaso você já tentou usar a propriedade scroll do overflow?

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Se você puder colocar o código no codepen facilitaria para ajudá-lo.